# Formatted Decimal has different behaviour for the "g" option when using "%" operator vs "format"

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
>>> "{:g}".format(Decimal('1.100'))
'1.100'
>>> "%g" % Decimal('1.100')
'1.1'
```

Is this just a bug in the decimal package or was it intended that format could have different behaviour than the old "%" operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://pyformat.info/:

> The new-style simple formatter calls by default the __format__() method of an object for its representation. If you just want to render the output of str(...) or repr(...) you can use the !s or !r conversion flags.

So `"{:g}".format(Decimal('1.100'))` first processes `__format__()` on the Decimal contents, while the other one probably first converts to a float prior to formatting.

`"{:g}".format(float(Decimal('1.100')))` gives `1.1`